# How to import DLL into the JAVA project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, dll

There is DLL file called as myAPI.dll. It contains classes that I'd like to use in my JAVA code. How to import this DLL file into my Java project in Eclipse? It should be possible to run the code based on something like this:

```
import myAPI;

   public class MyClass {
     //...
   }

}
```

Comment: That is C# code. "Java" is not an acronym and should not be written with capital letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know which language is used for your code snippet but it is definitely not java. Java does not have keywords like `using` and `namespace`.

Generally to call native code from java you have to use good old JNI or newer JNA.

Please follow the following links to get started with these technologies.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html

http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/1767

Answer (score 1):

*The code snippet you have shown is C#, not Java.* Now namespace lets you group logically related things. For e.g. all order processing related classes can be put under single namespace. It is also used as a mechanism to avoid/resolve name conflicts. It also defines the visibility scope of your class. Read [this lesson](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson06.aspx) for more details.